# Specflow ignores When step in F# step assembly

Tags: f#, specflow

I am using VS2010, SpecFlow 1.9.0, NUnit 2.6.2 and ReSharper 7.1. I have a feature file taken from the example:

```
Feature: SpecFlowFeature1
    In order to avoid silly mistakes
    As a math idiot
    I want to be told the sum of two numbers

@mytag
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
    And I have entered 70 into the calculator
    When I press the add button
    Then the result should be 120 on the screen
```

I have implemented the step definitions in a separate F# assembly:

```ml
[<TechTalk.SpecFlow.Binding>]
module StepDefinitions

open TechTalk.SpecFlow
open NUnit.Framework

let [<Given>] ``I have entered (.*) into the calculator`` (a: int) =
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending()

let [<When>] ``I press the add button`` =
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending()

let [<Then>] ``the result should be (.*) on the screen`` (r: int) =
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending()
```

I have told SpecFlow where to find them via the stepAssemblies tag in app.config

However, when I run the test, it finds the Given and Then steps, but not the When step. The error I get is:

```
No matching step definition found for one or more steps.
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Binding]
    public class StepDefinitions
    {
        [When(@"I press the add button")]
        public void WhenIPressTheAddButton()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }
    }
}

Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
-> pending: StepDefinitions.I have entered (.*) into the calculator(50)
And I have entered 70 into the calculator
-> skipped because of previous errors
When I press the add button
-> No matching step definition found for the step. Use the following code to create one:
        [When(@"I press the add button")]
        public void WhenIPressTheAddButton()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }

Then the result should be 120 on the screen
-> skipped because of previous errors
```

Have I gone wrong somewhere, or is there a bug with F# support?

Comment: The equivalent to the given C# is actually `let [<When>] ``I press the add button``() =
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending()` - note the extra `()` after `button`

Comment: Doh! I've been staring at that for ages. Sorry for the stupid question :( If you move your comment to an answer I can award you the points!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct translation of the C# is actually

```
let [<When>] ``I press the add button``() =
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending()
```

Note the extra `()`.  As this was missing in the original version, the function had a different signature which meant that it wasn't found.